# Pycharm- can not install opencv

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to PyCharm, and try to understand how I can install openCV package, and later cv2 package.
I saw an old disussion here, that suggets first to donwload the openCV from interent and then update the system interpreter.
I download the openCV and loacted it on the same directorty where I manage my project.
Is it good??

Many many thanks!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNcm8.png)

Answer (score 8):

Just one line:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

or
    `pip3 install opencv-python`

---

You can also:

[image: PyCharm install package]

Answer (score 1):

You can read the instructions on the jetbrains website to add a module/package.

They can be found here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Answer (score 0):

Add the Package in this Directory: `C:\Users\#####\PycharmProjects\Projectname\venv\Lib\site-packages` and run via cmd the `eays_install.py`