# Error:"No matching distribution found for opencv-python" in pycharm

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

1. I am currently working on a project which requires me to use opencv.
2. I am using PyCharm as my editor and I am facing a problem while
   downloading the opencv-python module in my project repository of
   pycharm.

   The error stated is:

> ```
> Collecting opencv-python
>
>   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
> No matching distribution found for opencv-python
> ```

Could any experienced PyCharm users help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm- can not install opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632134/pycharm-can-not-install-opencv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LimWZ

These errors because of `opencv` and `cv2` are not the `python` package names.

These are part of the `opencv-python` package available to install from `pip`.

For  `python 2`:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

For `python 3`:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Comment: If i were to use pip install opencv-python in my terminal, would that mean i can import cv2 on my pycharm? Sorry, I'm still new here

Comment: Yes, you can. just refer this link - https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Comment: Sweet. Thanks so much!