# PyCharm cannot find reference to OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

Okay, so after installing OpenCV and Numpy both on my machine, and also enabling and installing them again in Pycharm, I still get the error when writing the OpenCV code (no autocomplete). This is the erro:

```
Cannot find reference 'imshow' in '__init__.py'
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

**When I run it, the code works,** but it is really annoying that Pycharm doesn't recognize it. I tried all the solutions I could come up with, but it still persists. I uninstalled and then reinstalled everything (multiple times), set up different interpreters, but the issue still persists. I also tried installing different versions of both Python and OpenCV, but nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems OK, there is no quibble line underneath so I guess it recognizes it.

Comment: PyCharm normally creates VirtulaEnvironments for Python. Make sure OpenCV is in your VirtualEnvironment or try using the system interpreter.

Comment: Unfortunately neither works, I added OpenCV file to the venv/scripts and the issue still shows. Then I tried with system interpreter to no avail.

Comment: pycharm and opencv is a common issue. please look for previously answered questions. here's a previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632134/pycharm-can-not-install-opencv

Comment: as Christoph said, this is a well-know issue... there are some tricks in the official [YouTrack thread](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35691), but unfortunately they are inconsistent.

Comment: @baggiponte FWIW, workaround #1 in that thread worked for me, so thanks for sharing the link !

Comment: I am using the latest PyCharm version (professional tbh, since I have a student license) and haven't had this issue in a while. Still fails to recognize the top `import cv2` but that's because of an unrelated reason (I am using poetry)